# Selenium IE driver not working with img element

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this strange problem with img tags, my sample HTML code below

```
<html>
<input type='text' id='1111' MaxLength='10'/>
<img id='imageId001' title='hello' name='Done'/>
</html>

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("imageId001")).getAttribute("title"));
```

Using Chrome Driver, getting output as hello.

However with IE 64/32 webdrivers,
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == imageId001(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Whats wrong here???

Selenium WebDriver Version: 2.53.1.0
Internet Explorer : IE11
OS: Windows 7
JDK 1.7

Comment: Have you tried with a wait condition? maybe the the page was not loaded.If this does not work you should try these selectors manually in IE.

Comment: Yes, tried with both static and dynamic wait to ensure the page is loaded fully and using other selectors (xpath, etc.,) as well. I am not sure how to validate selectors in IE, but in chrome both xpath and id selectors locates the target element. Chrome is working like charm, but IE is causing the problem.

Comment: @BhuvaneshMani for trying out selectors in IE right click on element and choose inspect. Similar to chrome. Or else hit F12.

Comment: @Grasshopper, I use CTRL +B (Select element) which is other way of validating selectors, right? Then yes, its getting identified in IE, but Selenium IE drivers cannot.

Comment: Is Selenium IE driver able to pick the input element? How about trying a CSS locator for the img?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Mani, can you see the same element with same attributes in IE view source

Comment: @Grasshopper, Yes, input element gets picked up. Problem is with img. I dont want to use alternative workarounds but  want to understand why IE behave differently. Because my test suite should run irrespective of browsers and hence need to know the root cause.

Comment: @ChanChow, yes i can see same attributes in developer tools of both chrome and IE, no diff

Comment: @Grasshopper, Sorry. I am wrong. IE didnt recognize neither input / img elements. I created this question with input ele just for reference. But my actual issue in my application is with img tag.

Comment: have u setup the driver correctly taken the 32\64 bit into consideration. seems for ie11 u need some registry settings. check it out -- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.

Comment: I setup registry settings as recommended, but still the problem remains same. Its not detecting the webelements on simple html page. Is there any other alternative should i need to consider? I am struck here! tried to lookup for setting the browser mode to lower than IE11, but that seems to be impossible with IEDriver now. what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of effort spent, i figured out the cause. When i ran above code, i noticed a warning text displayed at bottom of IE as "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls. " along with button "Allow blocked content". Since i have webdriverwait waiting for my img element, i clicked on this button and i saw that driver started printing the output which i was looking for (Same as chrome).

So i think driver object is not attached to browser if IE throws up some warnings like thsi. I solved it by disabling 2 options in Internet Options > Advanced Tab > Security section >

- Allow active content from CDs to run on My Computer -> Set to Yes (ticked)
- Allow active content to run in files on My Computer -> Set to Yes (ticked)

After this, my driver started identifying objects and works like chrome.

Note: Also i wanted to narrow down if registry setting played a role here as suggested by @Grasshopper. So I did same experiment in my colleague's machine (doesn't have registry settings for IE11) and this resolved for him as well. So registry setting does not play role here.